# woocommerce product gallery images upload from front-end

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i created a code which publish product from front-end issue is when i upload gallery images from frontend only last image upload.

here is code

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  <input type="file" name="agp_gallery[]" id="agp_image_files" style="width:90%; margin-left:5px;" multiple>
```

here is function multiupload

```
  agp_process_image('agp_image_file', $post_id, $result['caption'], $result['content'], $result['author']);
          if ( $_FILES ) {
$files = $_FILES['agp_gallery'];
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
if ($files['name'][$key]) {
$file = array(
'name' => $files['name'][$key],
'type' => $files['type'][$key],
'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
'error' => $files['error'][$key],
'size' => $files['size'][$key]
);

$_FILES = array("agp_gallery" => $file);

foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {

    agp_process_wooimage($file, $post_id, $result['caption']);
}
}
}
}
```

here is main function

```
function agp_process_wooimage($file, $post_id, $caption){

     if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();


  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);

  update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attachment_id);

  $attachment_data = array(
    'ID' => $attachment_id,
    'post_excerpt' => $caption
  );

  wp_update_post($attachment_data);

  return $attachment_id;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a final code :-

```
  // Get the upload attachment files
   if ( $_FILES ) {
$files = $_FILES['agp_gallery'];
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
if ($files['name'][$key]) {
$file = array(
'name' => $files['name'][$key],
'type' => $files['type'][$key],
'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
'error' => $files['error'][$key],
'size' => $files['size'][$key]
);

            $_FILES = array("agp_gallery" => $file);

            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array)
            {
                $newupload = agp_process_wooimage($file,$post_id);
            }
        }

    }
 }

function agp_process_wooimage($file, $post_id){

     if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();


  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);
 update_post_meta($post_id,  array_push($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attachment_id));

  return $attachment_id;

}
```