# Is there a way I can create an upload function for photos which will then display in a gallery in HTML/CSS for Weebly?

Tags: html, css, file-upload, image-gallery, weebly

I am looking for some code to help me...

Problem: I want to be able to create a picture gallery in `CSS` or `HTML` (Weebly) where by external users can upload a photo (or multiple) and it will then display in the gallery of the website.

I have looked at:
[woocommerce product gallery images upload from front-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292494/woocommerce-product-gallery-images-upload-from-front-end)

and

[upload photo for a html project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565644/upload-photo-for-a-html-project)

But they seem to only really focus on creating the gallery.  Weebly already has a low code version for a gallery, but I can't find a way of allowing others to be able to upload to it.

Ideal solution: some HTML/CSS which will allow people to upload multiple images (but it will check they are all *.jpg, or *.tiff or *.png) and then add them to a rotating gallery on the page.   It will allow me to go in and modify the images/delete images if inappropriate.

Reason: Someone has passed away, and I am looking to create a repository for all of the friends and family to upload all of the photos they have of this person so we can create a database.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not possible to have a visitor upload a image to a gallery using the Weebly platform. You CAN, however, use a contact form and the file upload feature in the form to have the visitor submit the photo then upload it yourself. Alternately, there may be a 3rd party service that would allow this type of functionality.

Comment: Thanks, Jeffrey, I thought that, but wondered if anyone knew of any 3rd party stuff I could incorprorate as possibly an iframe or something?